# Mocking Computer System Date Time

Tags: c#, windows-services, mocking

I have built a Windows Service in C# that calls live timeseries data from a database based on the current date and time.
I have test data in a test Databse that I would like to use to calculate if the data was being used in the correct way.
I was wondering if anyone has used an application or has any other way to "Mock" the system date on your local computer. So for example I can just run this application and set it to set my system date to a specified date.

Any advice would be great.

Comment: You mean `How to mock DateTime.Now in unit tests?`

Comment: Take a look at [NodeTime](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) unit tests.

Comment: I have already mocked the time in my unit tests to test different logic I have but now I actually want to run the windows service on my local computer just to see if it does everything I expect.

Answer (score 12):

Just encapsulate your access to the `DateTime.Now` property behind an interface.

```
public interface IDateTimeProvider
{
    DateTime Now { get; }
}
```

In your code, use an implementation like this:

```
public class DateTimeProvider : IDateTimeProvider
{
    public DateTime Now { get { return DateTime.Now; } }
}
```

And for your tests, you can just mock `IDateTimeProvider` by creating a test class or by using a mocking framework.

If you use this interface with a technique like depency injection, it's easy to alter the behaviour of your service, even at runtime.

You could e.g. create an `IDateTimeProvider` that is always some hours off:

```
public class AlwaysToLateDateTimeProvider : IDateTimeProvider
{
    public DateTime Now { get { return DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2); } }
}
```

or create an implementation that reads the 'mocked' datetime from a file, a database, a pipe etc.

While testing, you would configure your service to use one of those implementations, and while running in live mode, just configure your dependency injection to use the ordinary implementation that returns the 'right' date time.

---

And there is of course [TypeMock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/)...

```
Isolate.WhenCalled(() => DateTime.Now).WillReturn(new DateTime(2008, 1, 1));
```

Comment: AFAIK, because DateTime.Now is non-virtual, then you will need the paid version of TypeMock Isolator in order to use WhenCalled like this.

Answer (score 4):

I've used this to be able to override now, for instance when running tests. In your actual implementation where you use DateTime.Now you use the new SystemTime.Now instead. In your tests you just set the Now to a different function that returns your chosen value.

```
public static class SystemTime
{
    private static Func<DateTime> now = () => DateTime.Now;

    public static Func<DateTime> Now
    {
        get { return now; }
        set { now = value; }
    }
}
```

Example usage in test:

```
SystemTime.Now = () => DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20);
```

In the unit test teardown it's important to set it back with `SystemTime.Now = () => DateTime.Now`

Normal usage:

```
DateTime now = SystemTime.Now();
```

Comment: +1 for good idea. if using this code make shure that in your unittest-teardown-code the original value of the now-lamda expression is restored. Else other unittests may show unexpected results depending on the previos run test.

Comment: This will also fail when running time dependent unit tests in parallel due to the singleton nature of what is proposed here. Only real solutions to this problem are using something like Moles/Fakes or TypeMock for a quick easy solution without changing existing code. Otherwise, you are talking about refactoring potentially a lot of existing code to use something similar to JonathanK's response with dependency injection

Answer (score 0):

Much like the solution from Mharlin, the implementation below provides a one-for-one replacement of `DateTime.Now`. What's been added are some convenience methods for manipulating time in unit tests. What's been modified is the need to explicitly execute the action that returns a `DateTime`, which more closely resembles `DateTime.Now` usage.

```
public static class SystemTime
{
    private static Func<DateTime> now = () => DateTime.Now;

    public static DateTime Now
    {
        get { return now(); }
    }

    public static void Set(DateTime dt)
    {
        now = () => dt;
    }

    public static void MoveForward(TimeSpan ts)
    {
        var dt = now().Add(ts);
        Set(dt);
    }

    public static void Reset()
    {
        now = () => DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Example usage in production code:

```
var twentyMinutesFromNow = SystemTime.Now.AddMinutes(20);
```

Example usage in a time-sensitive test (this one verifies cache expiration):

```
// Set(): effectively lock the system clock at a specific time
SystemTime.Set(new DateTime(2015, 1, 1));

RunCodeThatFetchesDataAndCachesIt();

// MoveForward(): easily move the clock relative to current time with an
//  arbitrary TimeSpan
SystemTime.MoveForward(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

RunCodeThatFetchesDataAndCachesIt();
VerifyExpectationThatDataWasFetchedTwice();

// Reset(): return to the normal behavior of returning the current
//   DateTime.Now value
SystemTime.Reset();
```